# Save Logging messages when I click html link using log4j in java web application

Tags: java, jsp, logging, web, log4j

I need to save the logging messages into file when I click html link. I created dynamic web project and .jsp web file in eclipse. Also I'm using log4j for logging.

For now I create log4j.properties file to save logging messages in file. Also I implemented Logger:

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
```

and the message:

```
logger.info("start app");
```

But I need to save logging when I click some web page link or liked text from the created .jsp file. Something like this logging message:

```
2014-06-03 09:53:36,001 INFO root:01 - start app
2014-06-03 09:55:01,002 INFO root:02 - Selected: LINKED TEXT
```

Please help or suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific about your situation. What have you done so far, and what is still unimplemented? How do you store logs for now? And what do you mean with "when I lick HTML"?

Comment: just checking... maybe you just want to redirect the logs that are shown in eclipse into a file when you're running a dynamic web project, is that right?

Comment: @leo no... I just want to save the logging when I click some linked text or liked web page from .jsp file.

Comment: you mean, you'll start to write the logs after you click on some link, right? because logs are actually a stream

Comment: @leo Yes...Can you please help or suggest something?

Comment: sure, just gimme some minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how JSP works.

JSP is converted to a servlet, that runs in the server side, serving http requests.

When you click on a link in the browser, you're generating an event in the browser. This event may or may not generate a http request, and this request may or may not be sent to your servlet.

If you need to capture the events in the browser, you have two ways I guess

[1] capture the events in the client side, using for example a browser plugin. This is how automation plugins such as selenium works. They are pieces of code that run in the browser (in the client).

[2] attach some javascript code in your page to the click event on every link, so if someone clicks on some anchor element, you also generate a http request to your servlet so you can log the event. The problem of this approach is that you need javascript code for all your pages in order to do that.

Comment: thank you for your answer I really appreciated, but I don't need to enable or disable logging. I need when i click some link to be saved in logging file, if it's possible.

Comment: you've said "Save Logging messages when I click html link using log4j in java web application"

Comment: please be more specific. first what do you want to save in the logging file and second what do you mean by "to be saved in the logging file"? of course that if you have a logger, the contents are going to a logging file

Comment: you want to log the EVENT OF CLICKING THE LINK, is that?

Comment: I created search form...when I search for some keyword I have list of hyperlink texts. When I click some hyperlink text I want to be saved in logging. For example: 2014-06-03 09:55:01,002 INFO root:02 - Selected: LINKED TEXT

Comment: The links are external. Can you please help me with some javascript code for storing logging messages in file when the click event is used. Thanks